# jQuery & CSS, 2 li elements per row

Tags: jquery, css, html-lists

I have tried to sort my li so that I have 2 li elements per row.

Here is to see my js fiddle: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marco3/j9vCH/9/)

I think I have problems with the css, right? Can someone tell me where my error is?

Every li has a float and every second li has a class "secondElement" which doesn't float.

This second class I add using jquery:

```
$('div.pagination ul li').each(function(index) {
    if(index % 2) {
        $(this).addClass('secondElement');
    }
});
```

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VHFyd/1/

Comment: How about http://jsfiddle.net/j9vCH/12/ ?

Comment: @Morpheus-> thanke you, this works fine :)